# Error when creating StreamWriter object

Tags: c#

I can't solve this error! I get a red underline in VisualStudio 2010 below outfile in the second row. I have written the code exactly as it is in my book.

```
FileStream outFile = new FileStream("movies.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outFile);
```

The error message: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'MyMovies.FileManager.outFile'

I also have a question about saving a textfile if there is possible to save or replace a string of text at selected row in a file?

EDIT: The code I use to save

```
 StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText("MinaFilmer/filmer.txt");
 writer.WriteLine("Test");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that in the book, these are *local* variables, declared inside a method - whereas you're declaring them directly in a class as *instance* variables.

Do you *really* want these to be instance variables? Both of them? Where possible, I'd *attempt* to do this only within a method, so you can keep all the clean-up local to the method.

You *could* write this:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("movies.txt", 
                                          FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));
```

although you'd be better with:

```
StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText("movies.txt");
```

Then:

> I also have a question about saving a textfile if there is possible to save or replace a string of text at selected row in a file?

We'd need more detail to answer that, and it really is a separate question, which should be asked separately.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, should I use both line of your code or just the last one?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: How would you use both lines of code? That would be declaring the same variable twice.

Comment: Sorry, but when I'm using the second line, I just get an empty file?

Comment: Working now! For some strange reason I got a line break in the code. Thanks!

Comment: I thought i worked, but the file is empty again!? What could I have done wrong?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: I can't possibly tell without seeing your code. All we've seen is the code used to create the file, which obviously wouldn't include any data.

Comment: I made an edit to my question to show part of the code I use. Could the problem be that I once used writer.Close()? I removed that since I got an error when I was trying to save a second time. I guess I can't save again if I have closed the file

Comment: @3D-kreativ: Yes, you need to close the file... ideally by doing all of this in a `using` directive. But it now seems we're outside the scope of the original question. SO comments aren't good for remote interactive debugging... I would suggest you start a *new* question with a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for suggestions on writing a good question.

Comment: @3D-kreativ: No, because you're changing the question over time. You originally asked about one problem (the compile-time error) and then changed it to include a second one. There should be *one* problem per question. You also need to take a step back and spend a bit of time coming up with a good, well-written question which includes all the relevant information. Follow the link in my previous comment and read it thoroughly.